# A table of contents for each section. Including only the entries of that section

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I am preparing a presentation on Beamer and I will have different sections.
I would like to put a title page and a table of contents for each of the section. 
In particular, for each section a toc with only the entries of that section.
For example, suppose I have

1. Sec 1

   1.1. Subsec 1

   1.2. Subsec 2
2. Sec 2

   2.1. Subsec 1

   2.2. Subsec 2

   2.3. Subsec 3
3. Sec 3

   3.1. Subsec 1

   3.2 Subsec 2

At the beginning of sec 2 I would like a slide showing the title Sec 2 and at the following slide I want to see:
 2. Sec 2

2.1. Subsec 1

2.2. Subsec 2

2.3. Subsec 3

I have used the following code:

```
 \documentclass[t,10pt]{beamer}

\title{My presentation}

\date[February 11, 2015] % (optional)
{}

\def\sectionname{\translate{Section}}
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
  \begin{centering}
    \vskip1em\par

    \vspace{3cm}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt,center]{part title}
  \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page2}
{\tableofcontents[currentsection, sectionstyle=show, subsectionstyle=show]}

\def\sectionpage{\usebeamertemplate*{section page}}

\def\sectionpageBis{\usebeamertemplate*{section page2}}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage} \frame{\sectionpageBis}}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\footnotesize
  \tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=hide]
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{sub 1}
\subsection{sub 2}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{sub 1}
\subsection{sub 2}
\subsection{sub 3}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{sub 1}
\subsection{sub 2}
\end{document}
```

The title page works fantastically. However the toc shows the name of the other sections and other subsections.
Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi Erik thanks for the advice. I did add a compilable example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your definition of `section page2` to the following:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section page2}
{\tableofcontents[currentsection, sectionstyle=show/hide, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]}
```

For `sectionstyle`, `show/hide` means show the current section and hide other sections. For `subsectionstyle`, the three options are for the current subsection, other subsections within the same section, and other subsections in different sections. You also have the `shaded` option, which makes the entry somewhat transparent.  See the `beamer` documentation section 10.5 for details.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[t,10pt]{beamer}
\title{My presentation}
\date[February 11, 2015] % (optional)
{}

\def\sectionname{\translate{Section}}
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
  \begin{centering}
    \vskip1em\par

    \vspace{3cm}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt,center]{part title}
  \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page2}
{\tableofcontents[currentsection, sectionstyle=show/hide, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]}

\def\sectionpage{\usebeamertemplate*{section page}}
\def\sectionpageBis{\usebeamertemplate*{section page2}}

\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage} \frame{\sectionpageBis}}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\footnotesize
  \tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=hide]
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{sub 1}
\subsection{sub 2}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{sub 1}
\subsection{sub 2}
\subsection{sub 3}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{sub 1}
\subsection{sub 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it works!! Just a small additional question. What if I want to add the title `Outline`?

Comment: You could just add `\frametitle{Outline}` in your `\AtBeginSection` statement, like this: `\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage} \frame{\frametitle{Outline}\sectionpageBis}}`

Comment: By the way, the way you're using `section page` is similar to the default behavior of parts. You might consider using parts with `\AtBeginPart{\frame{\partpage}}` in addition to sections. It may save you from having to customize so much.